# How to insert a checkmark in emacs -nw/gui-less mode

Tags: macos, unicode, emacs, terminal.app

I want to insert a tick mark, maybe this: ✔

Can I do it with C-x 8 or some other way?

My environment:
Latest MacOS, inside Terminal.app
I start with emacsclient -nw (No gui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `C-x 8 RET` followed by the name of the Unicode character or its hex code point.

In this case, you probably want character `CHECK MARK`, which has code point `2713`. So either of these works:

- `C-x 8 RET check mark RET`
- `C-x 8 RET 2713 RET`